# How to make the natural language for Emacs be English?

Tags: config, localization

My computer's default language is Portuguese, and I don't want to change that. But, for some usages (especially programming) it's better to have English output, for example to copy/paste an error message on a search engine.

I would like to have emacs in English only, to have for example eshell or built-in gdb output in English.

It sounds easy but I didn't find out how to do. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of any localization for Emacs. Do you have any specific examples that use anything else than English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to have emacs in English only,

Emacs is already English only.

> to have for example eshell or built-in gdb output in English.

gdb output is not builtin to Emacs, it comes from gdb.  By eshell, I assume you refer to external programs which you call from eshell.

On a Unixish system, you can tell programs to use non-localized message and settings by setting the environment variable `LC_ALL`.  To set that in Emacs, use

```
(setenv "LC_ALL" "C")
```

`C` is the standard non-localized locale.  See also

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do
- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I now understand the problem, and your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2007-07/msg00479.html) seems relevant. Emacs does not (yet) provide a way to configure it for a given natural language.

You can, however, configure the Emacs calendar to use local holidays and such. See [Calendar Localization](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CalendarLocalization) on Emacs Wiki.

But please do point to specific things that appear in Portuguese with your Emacs release, in case someone here has a suggestion for how to make that part use English instead.